# Send Email using spring?

Tags: spring, email

Thanks in advance. I have to send mail using spring. When i tried the code it shows following Bean Exception in my console.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' defined in class path resource [mail-simple.xml]:
  Instantiation of bean failed; 
  nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that 
      is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException.

  Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that 
      is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException
```

Can anyone please help me to find this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen anything like this, but the exception seems to be saying that it is trying to load a malformed class file for `javax.mail.MessagingException`.  I suggest that you download a fresh copy of the JAR file that contains that class, etcetera.

Comment: @shiva - are you *still* getting that exception?  Did downloading a fresh copy cure the problem?

Comment: I have downloaded new copy of jar files in my program. Still the same error is arrive. Do u want anymore error message to find the issue in this?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the output.I can send mail from specified SMTP to others.